# Wait for promise in RootCtrl Angular $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http, angularjs-scope

I have a method in my RootCtrl that makes a call to my http api, and returns the result.

```
$scope.checkAccess = function(){
    var result = MyService.me();
    result.then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data != 'false'){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

But when I try to call this method in one of the child controllers, like so...

```
var access = $scope.checkAccess();
```

it tells me `access` is undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is what the Service call looks like.

```
me: function() {
    return $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/me',
        method: 'GET'
      });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to actually return the promise object.

Here you go:

```
$scope.checkAccess = function(){
    var result = MyService.me();
    return result.then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data != 'false'){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @OP, note however that `access` will contain a promise object, not the value. you'll have to then use.. `.then()` with a callback to get the boolean value.